# How to find the average value of cell matrix?

Tags: matlab

I want to find the average value of cell matrix.

Comment: Give an example to clarify

Comment: increment: `x = x + 1`, decrement: `x = x - 1`

Comment: @Dan I really do not believe OP could not figure out such a basic answer by him/her self, I think he/she wants something else. :)

Comment: @Nishant then he/she is welcome to clarify. My comment does not stop the OP fro receiving further answers should someone telepathic know what is being asked that is not being asked.

Comment: i think i know what he wants, but the answer is to long for a comment and since i only guess not fit for an answer... Do you want a method where you can specify either increment or decrement depending rather your element is odd or even?

Comment: @TheMinion: That is also my understanding of what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go with the assumption that you want to **increment** if an element in the matrix is odd and **decrement** if an element in your matrix is even.  If you recall, a number having a remainder of 1 when you divide by 2 is odd, and having no remainder is even.  You can easily capture this using the `mod` command.

To start, let's say we have this 5 x 5 matrix:

```
A = vec2mat(1:25,5)

A =

 1     2     3     4     5
 6     7     8     9    10
11    12    13    14    15
16    17    18    19    20
21    22    23    24    25
```

Let's find what the remainder is for all of the numbers once we divide by 2.

```
remA = mod(A,2)

remA =

 1     0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     1     0
 1     0     1     0     1
 0     1     0     1     0
 1     0     1     0     1
```

As you can see, all numbers that are `1` are odd numbers, while ones that are `0` are even.  Let's set all of the numbers that are `0` to `-1`.

```
remA(remA == 0) = -1

remA =

 1    -1     1    -1     1
-1     1    -1     1    -1
 1    -1     1    -1     1
-1     1    -1     1    -1
 1    -1     1    -1     1
```

Now, simply take this matrix and add this with `A`:

```
finalA = A + remA

finalA =

 2     1     4     3     6
 5     8     7    10     9
12    11    14    13    16
15    18    17    20    19
22    21    24    23    26
```

We can reverse this logic if you want to **decrement** for odd numbers and **increment** for even numbers by taking the `remA` right after changing the entries from `0` to `-1` and **subtracting** instead of adding.  In other words:

```
finalA = A - remA

finalA =

 0     3     2     5     4
 7     6     9     8    11
10    13    12    15    14
17    16    19    18    21
20    23    22    25    24
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thnx dear, Is it possible to check the matrix element according to row col. wise and then check even and odd no. If it is even then increase this particular element by one and store this matrix in new matrix and finally print this new matrix.

Comment: I think I have done what you are asking in my post.